# How can I programatically select a drop down option using Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my sample drop down

```
<select name="newType" class="parts-select full-width-combo" onchange={{action "loadFilter" value="target.value" }}>
            <option value="" selected  hidden >Select </option>
            {{#each model as |item|}}
                <option value="{{item.id}}">{{item.description}}</option>
            {{/each}}
 </select>
```

from the relevant template action I wanted to set this selected item dynamically.

As an example it default selected by "Select" and then based on some button click on that page and need to set my selected option to other selected option to be selected.
I am not using any plugin and I can't do it here.

Comment: Is It OK to use Jquery inside my controller action for this ?is that correct ember way of doing >

Comment: you can add a property to item called selected and in your option elements you can do this `<option selected={{item.selected}}>`. There are other ways to do it too, by using a helper, for example. I think using jquery can also work. Just check that the onchange action for the select is being triggered properly.

Comment: Pragmatic means something very different (*in a sensible and realistic way that is based on practical rather than theoretical considerations.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers)' `eq` helper to set which option is selected. I believe I have coded what you are asking at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f76da576d52e7f8ef1d9e7ab592abe2b?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). See `my-component.hbs` about how I used `eq` helper to set `selected` attributes of each option.

By the way I suggest using [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/) for select box instead of trying to write your own select with options.

Answer (score 7):

I used [mut helper](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_mut) to set directly to `selectedItemId` property. so onchange it will update it automaticaly. also used [ember-truth-helper](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) for eq helper to decide particular item is selected or not.

```
<select name="newType" class="parts-select full-width-combo" onchange={{action (mut selectedItemId) value="target.value" }}>
            <option value="" selected  hidden >Select </option>
            {{#each model as |item|}}
                <option value="{{item.id}}" selected={{if (eq item.id selectedItemId) 'true'}}>{{item.description}}</option>
            {{/each}}
 </select>
```