# Ember JS: select list with selected value

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a select component. In which I need to select an option based on the value in object.

Found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094665/2651934)

Implemented same:

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected disabled >Select </option>
  {{#each sourceTypes as |sourceType|}}
    <option value={{sourceType.id}} selected={{if (eq sourceType.id selectedOption) 'true'}}>{{sourceType.type}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Here `sourceType.id` is `id` for current option and `selectedOption` is sourceType reference in source object. Type is number in REST service response for both of them.

When I tried to print value of `eq sourceType.id selectedOption` in option  it is giving me false. Then I checked for `eq` documentation, it is `a === b`

1. Why is it giving false even if value and type both are same.
2. Is there any way to just check for value like `a == b`.

Comment: Did you verify on the console that in fact both values are the same? Maybe one of them is in a string form (has happened to me).

Comment: Thanks @FutoRicky It helped me. REST service was returning number, but ember was treating id as string, so I changed REST service to return string

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: If it solved could you auto aswer and close the question.

Comment: @heat, I changed the type in service response, but it may not be possible for everyone. Someone can post answer for comparing data ignoring type i.e. `a == b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to just check for value like a == b.

You can implement a custom helper that does this (see https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/templates/writing-helpers/)

```
import { helper } from "@ember/component/helper"

export default helper(function([a, b]) {
  return a == b;
});
```